# Syntax highlighting of inline comments wrong for INI files

Tags: notepad++

When editing an INI file, if I put an inline comment at the end of a declaration then the color of that comment is not the same as the color of the normal comment below. How can I make them the same?

[image: NotepadPlusPlus Example]

Answer (score 3):

it's an inner-program issue. changing comment color wont help you. cause it doesn't detect your code as comment to colorize. and it can considered as a bug. report it to Notepad++ developers to fix.

Comment: Whether it's a bug will vary – many programs use ini-style configuration, but very few of them support inline comments.

Comment: my sublime text doesn't have bug like that

Comment: @Manadmg it doesn't have bug cause you used all the line to comment. not part of it.(Actually your first character is `;` and program knows just these kind of comments and colorized it)

Answer (score 0):

The colorization is actually more correct this way. There is no actual "end of line" comments in ini files. If you request the value for the key "fight" through the native API, you will receive "fight.def;Fight definition filename". Your own API wrapper might then go ahead and remove the comment part, because it knows there are no semicolon characters allowed in your ini file values, but as per Windows API, the semicolon and all trailing characters still belong to the value.

Comment: please no excuses, are u notepad++ developers? where is the source on your statement? show me the source

Comment: @Manadmg [Windows 3.1 API specification ECMA-234](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-234/), volume 2, page 61, section 405.2: "Lines **starting** with the "#" or ";" character are comments strings [...]. Data lines within a named section consist of a key string followed by the "=" character, followed by the key data." Since your line starts with a key string followed by the "=" character, it is by definition a "data line". And everything that follows the "=" in a data line is considered "key data", including a semicolon and everything thereafter.